# Confused! PHP If not working

Tags: php, function, if-statement

I'm slightly confused. Probably just me being very thick! Basically, I have the following function:

```
// Check if a verified email
function verified($username)
{
    global $conn;
    if($username == '') { return; } 
    $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='".$username."' AND Verified = 1");
    $q->execute();

    return $q->rowCount();
}
```

And then I have the following code in my script:

```
if (verified($_SESSION['Username'] == '0')
```

Now I have echoed out the function as above and it returns `0` as it should but for some reason that if above doesn't seem to be agreeing that it is indeed a `0`. What am I doing wrong?!

Comment: is there a closing bracket missing? `if (verified($_SESSION['Username']) == '0')`

Comment: Does $_SESSION['Username'] return '0' or 0 ?

Comment: if (verified($_SESSION['Username']) == '0') you are missing closing brace

Comment: Obligatory "never use 'global'" comment.  Never use 'global' for anything, ever.  Instead, pass whatever the function needs in order to work through it's argument list, like you did with `$username`.

Comment: @KevinM1: It also reeks of SQL injection... Comparing with only two equal signs is also evil :-)

Comment: Also it would be slightly better to `SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt` and return `$row['cnt'];`, if you only need the number of rows, or at least someting like `SELECT ID`, would save some RAM..

Comment: @Etan dunno about injection as he's using prepared statements....

Comment: @KevinM1 yeah but he does not bind. This is still unprepared.

Comment: @AmazingDreams Good point.  Didn't even see that.  Just saw the `$conn->prepare` bit and skipped over the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you mean:

```
if (verified($_SESSION['Username']) == '0')
```

Note the closing parenthesis after $_SESSION['Username']...

Comment: If that's the problem, it would not even run ;-)

Comment: If you weren't aware there is a time limit to do so.

Answer (score 0):

This line is not correct:

```
if (verified($_SESSION['Username'] == '0')
```

You are missing a ')' after the $_SESSION['Username']. And the result will be an integer (rowcount), so the '' aren't needed

```
if (verified($_SESSION['Username']) == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

if mistake on copy-paste , its ok,otherwise check

if (verified($_SESSION['Username']**)** == '0')

check the proper '**)**' after ['Username']

then check for `session_start();` before a    `$_SESSION['Username']`